# Java: Simple way to Convert a Big String to Smaller fixed length String

Tags: java, string, oracle

I am working on a problem where I need to Compare Content of JSON Objects.I have to do that repeatedly for many records. I can not do Apple to Apple comparison as I have to skip few fields for comparison and also the data in Arrays may have different order.

**For Ex,** Following JSONs considered to have same content even though they have

- Different "id" value.
- Different Sequence of values in "interests"
  Array.

**Json1:**

```
{
"id":1,
"name":"John",
"dept":"HR",
"interests":["Reading","Cycling"]
}
```

**Json2:**

```
{
"id":5,
"name":"John",
"dept":"HR",
"interests":["Cycling","Reading"]
}
```

Our Plan was to create a table and port the comparison logic to Database Query. This data will be used to do some other operations later on.

- **id** NUMBER(10)
- **name** VARCHAR(256)
- **dept** VARCHAR(256)
- **interests** VARCHAR(256)

The fields which maps to database columns(id, name, dept) are good for querying directly. The **interests** values can grow and they are dynamic, I want to write a **method** to generate a unique String using the values from "interests" array, so that I do not have to store the entire String into the table.

I will call the **method** to generate the String, populate as value for **interests** column and  insert in to table, while querying as well, I will be using same **method** to populate my query parameters.

**Note:** My JSONs have few more complex Objects, for simplification purpose, I have took simple JSONs.

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. It's not entirely clear what you're trying to achieve here. You want to store a string as fixed length. If you're willing to sacrifice information you can either simply truncate the text (i.e., cut it at the desired length) or calculate a hash. If not, you _may_ be able to compress the string to some extent, but this solution will not be able to handle unlimited strings.

Comment: So, what's the question and what have you already tried? Surely, you can try to [compress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_compression) your string, but it (1) will likely hit the performance even more than CLOB, (2) won't work remarkably well on randomly formatted strings.

Comment: The "correct" way would be to store each "interest" separately, in a linked table. Alternatively you could sort the values in that interests list, so you always store "cycling-reading".

Comment: Would interests ' ["Cycling"] ' or ' ["Cycling", "Reading", "Kiting"] ' match for you?

Comment: Separate table was thought through, but, as I have mentioned, we have many such complex elements with in JSON. Also,  ' ["Cycling"] ' or ' ["Cycling", "Reading", "Kiting"] ' are Not a match for us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to *somehow* store a long string in a short(er) space. The strategy depends on your needs. A few things to consider:

- Do you need to index the field (in order to perform `SELECT` based on this?)
- Do you need to compare the strings for equality? If so, are false positives acceptable?
- …

You have a few options, all with pros and cons.

## Proper one-to-many relational refering

As mentioned, the proper way to do this is to normalize the references. So, a table of `(id, interest)` tuples and another with `(data-id, interest-id)` references will ensures *no information loss*.

## Truncate the string

E.g., 18 chars:

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog -> The quick brown fo
The quick brown fox jumps over the fence    -> The quick brown fo
```

Truncating will lead to information loss whenever the resulting length is shorter than the input string. This may or may not be a problem. Depending on the input strings truncation can be done from either end (or, really, anywhere) of the input.

## Hash the string

E.g., [md5](http://www.miraclesalad.com/webtools/md5.php):

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog -> 9e107d9d372bb6826bd81d3542a419d6
The quick brown fox jumps over the fence    -> 26d68913b492ebb7fe734b973a358ab8
```

Again, this leads to information loss:

1. Hash collisions since the output space (size depends on algorithm) is smaller than the input space (practically unlimited)
2. Hashing is a one-way operation

However, if you can live with the risk of false positives this may be viable. As mentioned in a comment by @HansKesting, make sure to normalize the array values before hashing (order, casing.) The important property of this strategy is that the hash length is fixed.

## Compress the string

E.g., [deflate](http://www.txtwizard.net/compression):

```
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog <-> eJwLyUhVKCzNTM5WSCrKL89TSMuvUMgqzS0oVsgvSy1SKAFK5yRWVSqk5KcDAFvcD9o=
The quick brown fox jumps over the fence    <-> eJwLyUhVKCzNTM5WSCrKL89TSMuvUMgqzS0oVsgvSy1SKAFKp6XmJacCAC1yDsE=
```

Compressing the string gives you the opportunity to decompress the string back to it's original form. The downside is that the output length is variable and unknown – and that some type of input is better suited for compression than other.

---

**In conclusion**, reading from your question and comments, only the "proper" relational way seems correct but hashing may prove viable.